# create exe using launc4j java

Tags: java, launch4j

I have created an .exe file by luunch4j and build.xml ant file in Java but when I click .exe I'm getting "could not  find main class program will exit" kind of message. If I click on the .jar file it will also give me the "failed to load main class manifest attribute" message. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you a manifest file ?
In your manifest file, you give the entry point (class) where the `main(String[] args)` method is.

More detail : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Here a example :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Sealed: true

Main-Class: org.example.server.Lauch

Class-Path: lib\externalLib.jar
```

Comment: I usually save it at the root of the project.
The manifest is added to the jar, maybe you'll need to check/modify your build.xml

Comment: I had the same issue and indeed, my main class was not defined in the manifest. Once I solved this issue, the exe worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the solution for it was that I hadn't set the JRE6 (in my case) location. You must put it on the JRE tab, at the Bundled JRE Path field.